# Practice the mathematical induction

Tags: real-analysis

I want to Show that $(\alpha_1 \alpha_2 ... \alpha_n)^{1/n} \leq (1/n)(\alpha_1 +\alpha_2 +... +\alpha_n)$ by practice the mathematical induction but I don't know how.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . I think that might be AM/GM. If so, then good luck with the induction!

Comment: Do you mean $$(a_1a_2\cdot …\cdot a_n)^{1/n}\le \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n}{n}$$? But it must be $$a_i\geq 0$$ for all $$i=1..n$$

Comment: What are the $a_i$?  ?  Integers? Reals?  positive reals?

Comment: @fleablood -  I suspect we can assume they are non-negative reals or a subset of those

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction

Comment: This would be a very difficult thing to prove by standard induction.  By Jack D'Aurizio's link it'd be fairly straightforward with Cauchy and Strong induction but that's not the standarrd induction so that be unusual for practice.  Umberto P's answer will work for standard induction but it requires knowing a far more complicated theorem (and one that seems at first glance to probably be equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assume that $\alpha_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.

It will help you to know Young's inequality: if $a,b \ge 0$, $p,q > 1$, and $\dfrac 1p + \dfrac 1q = 1$, then $ab \le \dfrac {a^p}p + \dfrac {b^q}{q}.$

With $p = 1 + \dfrac 1n$, Young's inequality gives you 
\begin{align*} (\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n+1}} &= (\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_n)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \alpha_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \\&\le \frac{n}{n+1} (\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_n)^{\frac 1n} + \frac 1{n+1} \alpha_{n+1}.
\end{align*}

You can apply the induction step  if you know that $(\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n)^{\frac 1n} \le \dfrac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$.